# Sending a mail to multiple recipients using json

Tags: json, email

I am using seal application it is a printing Solution we are trying to send a mail from the application using its command.
The application reads the parameter of the mail from a JSON file so when we try to send a mail to a single recipient it works but we can't add multiple recipients.
thanks to help me. 
the format of the JSON file for single recipients

{"sender":"example@domain.com",
 "body-file":"",
 "transport":"NoSSL",
 "subject":"test",
 "body-text":"test",
 "smtp-server":"ip",
 "mime-type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
 "recipient":"example@domain.com"
 "port":"25"
}

Comment: Have you tried putting a `,` between the separate mails? E.g. `[MAIL_1, MAIL2]`, where `MAIL_1` is the JSON you put into your question.

Comment: could you send me the format ?? edit it in the object I have sent

Comment: [{"sender":"example@domain.com", "body-file":"", "transport":"NoSSL", "subject":"test", "body-text":"test", "smtp-server":"ip", "mime-type":"PLAIN_TEXT", "recipient":"example1@domain.com" "port":"25" },{"sender":"example@domain.com", "body-file":"", "transport":"NoSSL", "subject":"test", "body-text":"test", "smtp-server":"ip", "mime-type":"PLAIN_TEXT", "recipient":"example2@domain.com" "port":"25" }]

Comment: I did it I received this Error message on the console                        org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: Ok, try putting braces around `{}`. If that doesn't work try getting the manual of your printing solution to look, which format/structure it requires.